# Miller Indices of Goldnanoparticles from Turkevich and Frens method

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography, nanotechnology

I need the miller indices of gold nanoparticles that were synthesized after the route of Turkevich and Frens. I during my research I found a lot of publications, but it looks like no one measured it before.
Has someone an idea of what the miller indices can be? Or better a source or paper where I can found them?

Comment: How big are your particles. The method you mentioned produces average particle sizes of around 15 to 50 nm according to the paper I found. A study for Gold particles with average diameter of around 15 nm was conducted in the linked paper, they also assign the indices here. Maybe this helps

https://doi.org/10.1016/j.promfg.2019.02.025

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming* you refer to a record like this:

[image]

which I found in Kimling *et al.* in «Turkevich Method for Gold Nanoparticle Synthesis Revisited» ([2006JPhysChemB15700](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp061667w)) when reporting X-ray diffraction.